# Android showing progress bar for webview in android

Tags: android, for-loop, progress-bar, loading, html

In my apps loading webpage in Web view till that webpage loads need to show progress bar after that progress bar should go..i am using an activity....reply me soon waiting for your answer

```
04-26 18:02:36.791: D/AndroidRuntime(25114): Shutting down VM
04-26 18:02:36.791: W/dalvikvm(25114): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41250438)
04-26 18:02:36.811: E/AndroidRuntime(25114): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-26 18:02:36.811: E/AndroidRuntime(25114): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{in.androidapplicationdotin.tneb/in.androidapplicationdotin.tneb.Onlinepayment}: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-26 18:02:36.811: E/AndroidRuntime(25114):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2038)
04-26 18:02:36.811: E/AndroidRuntime(25114):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2139)
04-26 18:02:36.811: E/AndroidRuntime(25114):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:143)
04-26 18:02:36.811: E/AndroidRuntime(25114):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1241)
04-26 18:02:36.811: E/AndroidRuntime(25114):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-26 18:02:36.811: E/AndroidRuntime(25114):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-26 18:02:36.811: E/AndroidRuntime(25114):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4960)
04-26 18:02:36.811: E/AndroidRuntime(25114):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-26 18:02:36.811: E/AndroidRuntime(25114):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-26 18:02:36.811: E/AndroidRuntime(25114):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
04-26 18:02:36.811: E/AndroidRuntime(25114):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
04-26 18:02:36.811: E/AndroidRuntime(25114):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-26 18:02:36.811: E/AndroidRuntime(25114): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-26 18:02:36.811: E/AndroidRuntime(25114):    at android.content.ContextWrapper.getApplicationInfo(ContextWrapper.java:143)
04-26 18:02:36.811: E/AndroidRuntime(25114):    at android.view.ContextThemeWrapper.getTheme(ContextThemeWrapper.java:65)
04-26 18:02:36.811: E/AndroidRuntime(25114):    at android.app.AlertDialog.resolveDialogTheme(AlertDialog.java:142)
04-26 18:02:36.811: E/AndroidRuntime(25114):    at android.app.AlertDialog.<init>(AlertDialog.java:98)
04-26 18:02:36.811: E/AndroidRuntime(25114):    at android.app.ProgressDialog.<init>(ProgressDialog.java:77)
04-26 18:02:36.811: E/AndroidRuntime(25114):    at in.androidapplicationdotin.tneb.Onlinepayment.<init>(Onlinepayment.java:24)
04-26 18:02:36.811: E/AndroidRuntime(25114):    at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
04-26 18:02:36.811: E/AndroidRuntime(25114):    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
04-26 18:02:36.811: E/AndroidRuntime(25114):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1068)
04-26 18:02:36.811: E/AndroidRuntime(25114):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2029)
04-26 18:02:36.811: E/AndroidRuntime(25114):    ... 11 more
04-26 18:02:42.111: I/GATE(25114): <GATE-M>DEV_ACTION_COMPLETED</GATE-M>
04-26 18:03:30.431: I/Ads(25114): AdLoader timed out after 60000ms while loading the HTML.
04-26 18:03:30.571: I/Ads(25114): AdLoader timed out after 60000ms while loading the HTML.
04-26 18:05:44.491: I/Process(25114): Sending signal. PID: 25114 SIG: 9
```

Comment: That's not how StackOverflow works. You should do your research first and then tell us what you have tried. We can help if you have a problem. You can't just ask for code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code -

put this code in `onCreate()` Method

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new myWebClient());    
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.loadUrl("Your web url");

public class myWebClient extends WebViewClient


    {
        private ProgressDialog myProgressDialog;

        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
            myProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(YourActivity.this);
            myProgressDialog.setCancelable(false);
            myProgressDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


            return true;

        }
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        try{
            if (myProgressDialog != null)
                myProgressDialog.dismiss();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        }
        @Override
        public void doUpdateVisitedHistory(WebView view, String url,
                boolean isReload) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.doUpdateVisitedHistory(view, url, isReload);


        }

        @Override
        public void onLoadResource(WebView view, String url) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onLoadResource(view, url);



        }

    }
```

Hope this code helps you!!!!

If it is not working please let me know i will try to help you more..

Comment: Your always welcome..:) i like to help people i know the answer.:)

Comment: i am newer to android..thank for u help can u give ur personal mail id

Comment: i need to show word loading... in dialog box how to do it

Comment: i didn't understand what you wanna do?

Comment: what i asked was how to showing word loading in progress dialog....i have got output ..i am happy

Comment: means do you want custom progress bar? in which and text of progress will be showsn like 1 to 10?

Comment: please post an question over new thread so that i can give your answer here i am not able to give you code for custom progres bar

Comment: i got output for custom progress

Comment: so you can just set text in custom progress bar text.

Answer (score 1):

you can try this...

```
    private ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(WebActivity.this);

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.webview);
    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    String url=extras.getString("adres");

    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {                  
            if (dialog.isShowing()) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        }
    });
    dialog.setMessage("Loading..Please wait.");
    dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
    dialog.show();
    webView.loadUrl(url);

    WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
}
```

Comment: not working for me similar like this only give me some suggest

Comment: i am not able to post my logcat here can u give your mail id ...i am newer to android